# How to correct a "ModuleNotFoundError'" regarding a separate Python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, api, compiler-errors

So I am trying to implement an API just to experiment with it. For clarity reasons, I decided to have all my credentials regarding authentication in a separate folder called 'Authentication'

The organization of my folders are shown below

- API

  - Authentication

    - **init**.py (Formatting keeps bolding, but it has the 2 underscores on each side)
    - credentials.py
    - tokens.py
  - Resources

    - **init**.py
    - statusCodes.py
  - runRESTAPI

    - getNewAuth.py

Here is where the issue arises from the 'getNewAuth.py' file.

```
from Authentication import tokens, credentials
from Resources import statusCodes
import requests
import json
```

Since both the 'Authentication' and 'Resources' folders have the **init**.py files, 'getNewAuth.py' should be able to access them as modules.

However, when trying to run the file, I get an error that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getNewAuth.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Authentication import tokens, credentials
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Authentication'
```

Comment: I think you should add `__init__.py` in `runRESTAPI` folder

Comment: Didn't even think of that, added it, but sadly it didn't fix the issue, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be running getNewAuth.py directly,
 that makes runRESTAPI top-level package, either register Authentication as another package in PATH or copy the getNewAuth.py to root folder then try running

Comment: This works! So if I were to create any other files such as refreshAuth.py I would have to follow the same process correct? This would eventually have about 30 different files that would need to interact with both the Authentication and Resources folders.

Comment: You can add those to separate folders as well, but initial file that you run with python command must be root folder

Comment: create a main.py file in root folder that will import and execute some starting function from getNewAuth.py,